# How to keep scrollbars of a table in tact after a page refresh

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the 1st column and 1st row and frozen and have horizontal and vertical scrollbars to go through the entire table within a 500x500 div

When the page refreshes, I lose the position of the 2 scrollbars and the table pops back to the top

Is it possible to preserve the scrollbars?
I have a table where the 1st column and 1st row and frozen and have horizontal and vertical scrollbars to go through the entire table within a 500x500 div

When the page refreshes, I lose the position of the 2 scrollbars and the table pops back to the top

Is it possible to preserve the scrollbars?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.intro {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.table-grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 350px;
}

.table-grid table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.table-grid th,
.table-grid td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-grid thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* safari and ios need the tfoot itself to be position:sticky also */

.table-grid tfoot,
.table-grid tfoot th,
.table-grid tfoot td {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
}

th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #ccc;
}

thead th:first-child,
tfoot th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}


/*Highlight rows*/

.table_grid tr:hover,
.table_grid tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
}


/*Highlight rows including header
.table_grid tr:hover th,
.table_grid tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
}
*/

.mvcode_right:hover .mvtooltip_right {
  display: block;
}

.mvtooltip_right {
  display: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-grid">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            First top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Second top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Third top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Forth top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Fifth top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Sixth top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Seventh top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What Browser are you using? Scroll position is normally remembered.

Comment: I am using Chrome but the issue is with the scroll bars in the table. The browser scroll bars location are retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `scroll` event and store scroll position in localStorage:

```js
const table = document.querySelector(".table-grid");
table.scrollTop = localStorage.getItem("scrollTop");
table.scrollLeft = localStorage.getItem("scrollLeft");
table.addEventListener("scroll", e =>
{
  localStorage.setItem("scrollTop", e.target.scrollTop);
  localStorage.setItem("scrollLeft", e.target.scrollLeft);
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.intro {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.table-grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 350px;
}

.table-grid table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.table-grid th,
.table-grid td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-grid thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* safari and ios need the tfoot itself to be position:sticky also */

.table-grid tfoot,
.table-grid tfoot th,
.table-grid tfoot td {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
}

th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #ccc;
}

thead th:first-child,
tfoot th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}


/*Highlight rows*/

.table_grid tr:hover,
.table_grid tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
}


/*Highlight rows including header
.table_grid tr:hover th,
.table_grid tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
}
*/

.mvcode_right:hover .mvtooltip_right {
  display: block;
}

.mvtooltip_right {
  display: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-grid">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            First top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Second top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Third top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Forth top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Fifth top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Sixth top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="mvcode_right">
            Seventh top Column
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>Cell content<br> test </td>
        <td><a href="#">Cell content longer</a></td>
        <td>Cell content with more content and more content Cell </td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmdw538a/1/